# Live diff-mode editing in vim

Tags: vim, diff

I want a live view of diffs while I am editing a file.  `vimdiff` is able to do something I want, like highlighting the differences between two files.

However there are two drawbacks of `vimdiff` that holds me back.

First, it cannot buffer the same file independently to allow a `diff` comparison.  This problem can be easily worked around.  I have the following shell script (call it `diffvim`) to make `vimdiff` buffer the same file independently (by making a temporary copy of the file under editing).

```
#!/bin/sh

# Differentially Viming

TMPDIR=/tmp/diffvim
FILENM=$1
FILEBN=$(basename $FILENM)

if [ ! -d "$TMPDIR" ]; then
  mkdir $TMPDIR
fi

cp $FILENM $TMPDIR/$FILEBN && vimdiff $FILENM $TMPDIR/$FILEBN
```

The second drawback of `vimdiff` is that editing the *non-diff* parts of one of the two copies of the same file does not trigger `diff` to recalculate the differences.  One has to do it manually by invoking `:diffupdate`.  I want this recalculation to be automated.  The relatively convenient way I feel is to trigger it when I exit the *INSERT* mode and enter the *NORMAL* mode.  This again can be easily done by adding the following mapping to my `.vimrc` file:

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:diffu<CR>
```

However, it is not the perfect solution yet.  Because if I do some editing in the *NORMAL* mode, that is without entering and then exiting the *INSERT* mode, recalculation will still not be triggered automatically after the editing is done.  So I add another mapping to my `.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <Esc> :diffu<CR>
```

But this time, something strange happens.  When I open a file for editing, some of the standard key bindings malfunction.  For example, if I press key `h` or `l` (that is, any of them being the first command I issue after opening the file), all get me into *INSERT* mode, while key <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd> delete a line or the whole content, etc.  But if after opening the file, I press key <kbd>Esc</kbd> first, then those commands work fine.

Any idea what goes wrong?  Do you have a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into `autocmd` in vimdoc, I think I have found the solution that does exactly what I want:

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * diffupdate
```

Many thanks to Ingo for his suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

`<Esc>` is also used in several keycodes of special keys, and it plays a role in printing to the terminal.

It's a bad idea to overload it, especially with something so invasive like you did. Use a different key, e.g. `<Leader><Leader>`, or define a trigger on events:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave * diffupdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This kind of event trigger is cleaner solution.  Can I do it also in the *NORMAL* mode.  BTW, I have detailed my question.

Comment: Ah, I think I have found the solution.  Add also the event `CursorMoved`.